# How to test JSP TagExtraInfo?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I consistently have troubles getting my TagExtraInfo implementations to work properly. I have one implementation that works, and one that doesn't and I unable to see the difference between the two. And all the IDE's seem to have have "bugs/features" regarding this, which makes it hard to see where the problem actually is.

The relationship between a TagExtraInfo and a jsp tag should be reasonably well-defined, and I assuming I should be able to get some kind of compliance-testing software. Anyone know anything like this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/). That is a simple web container that can be started from your unit test. You can prepare a simple web.xml, test.jsp and monitor exceptions in order to see if everything works fine. There is an [interesting article](http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/testing-web-applications-with-jetty/).

Comment: Unfortunately, TagExtraInfo provides meta-data *to the IDE* that is used for intellisense and similar.

Comment: Ah, you want to test TagExtraInfo compliance with different IDEs, not with J2EE container, then I guess there is no simple answer to this question. But what kind of problems do you get with IDEs?